# How to map commands in Vim?

Tags: vim, text-editors, gvim, vimrc, gvimrc

I am using gVim and there's no vertical split option in it's File menu item.
I want to map the default `:split` and its abbreviation `:sp` to `:vsplit` and `:vsp` respectively, so that it replaces the horizontal split everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your problem: You're not using vim like vim. You're using vim like notepad++. If you were using vim like vim, you could simply do:

```
:vsplit file
```

(or even better, type `<C-w>v`)
and then you would not need a mouse, or a gui, or a menu or anything. Then, if you wanted to remap

```
:split
```

to

```
:vsplit
```

you could simply run

```
:cnoremap split vsplit
:cnoremap sp vsp
```

That would entirely solve your problem.

But that's not your problem. If you remapped these commands and then used the mouse to `:split` a file, the remappings will take no affect. So at this point, you really have two options.

1. which *I* much prefer, and highly recommend, is to stop using the menu buttons. Everytime you move your hand from the keyboard to the mouse, drag your mouse cursor up the menu button, scroll down, click the right button, browse through your files, click to open the right file, you have stopped using vim. You are now using notepad++ inside of vim. You could have done all the same in *two buttons!* (`<C-w>v`) If you want to take this approach to the extreme, you could also run

   ```
   :set guioptions=
   ```

   which will remove all menu buttons. However, since it's your workflow, you can go with option 2:
2. Add this to your `.vimrc`:

   ```
   an 10.320 &File.Sp&lit-Open\.\.\.<Tab>:vsp  :browse vsp<CR>
   ```

   This will add a "vertical split" option to your menu bar.

Comment: Glad I could help!